# Using Swift Shared Instance in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a shared instance of a class in Swift that I'm using in Objective-C. I'm unable to create the shared instance and use the instance function. Here's my Swift code.

```
class VideoPlayerSignaler: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = VideoPlayerSignaler()

    let playerAction = Signal<PlayerAction>()

    private override init() {

    }

    func firePlayerAction(action: PlayerAction) {
        playerAction.fire(action)
    }
}
```

Here's my Objective-C code.

```
VideoPlayerSignaler *signaler = [VideoPlayerSignaler sharedInstance];

// This is the line that is producing the issue. 
// It's as if the signaler variable is a Class Instance
[signaler firePlayerAction: PlayerAction.Stop];
```

The error I'm producing states that firePlayerAction does not exist. In essence, Objective C believes the `signaler` variable to be a class instance.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it so that `signaler` is a shared instance of `VideoPlayerSignaler`?

Comment: If you post your code for the signal class as well as the firstPlayerAction in Objective-C, I may be able to help.

Comment: What issue does it produce?

Comment: I can give you the library code. `https://github.com/artman/Signals`

Comment: In fact, signaler here is really a "Class instance"

Comment: That's what I thought. XCode doesn't recognize the function or the instance variable.

Comment: What is `PlayerAction`? Is it an enum? Is it marked `@objc`? Then you probably need `PlayerActionStop`.

Comment: It's not but I'll fix that once I can figure out how to get an instance of `VideoPlayerSignaler`.

Comment: I would love to know why someone thinks this question should be closed. Telling me why it's irrelevant helps me and others improve the question.

Comment: My guess would be the `PlayerAction` enum. Is it an `@objc` enum? If not, it  needs to be. And if it is, the cases export to ObjC like `PlayerActionStop`, not `PlayerAction.Stop`.

Comment: @rickster, Never thought that would be it. I knew I had to add the `@objc` but I didn't think it would be the issue. Post the answer and I'll give credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your Swift, or with how you access the singleton instance from ObjC — the problem is the enum value you're passing to it.

Presumably your enum declaration looks something like this:

```
enum PlayerAction: Int {
    case Stop, Collaborate, Listen // etc
}
```

To make your enum accessible to ObjC, you need to preface the declaration with `@objc`:

```
@objc enum PlayerAction: Int { /*...*/ }
```

This makes it appear as a Cocoa-style `NS_ENUM` declaration in ObjC, creating global symbols for case names by concatenating the Swift enum type's name with the case names:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PlayerAction) {
    PlayerActionStop = 1,
    PlayerActionCollaborate,
    PlayerActionListen, // etc
};
```

So those names are what you should be passing when you call a method taking an enum value from ObjC:

```
[signaler firePlayerAction: PlayerActionStop]; // NOT PlayerAction.Stop
```

(The only docs I can find to cite for this are buried in the [Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID347) chapter in *The Swift Programming Language* — scroll down the to `objc` attribute.)